# Windows Azure, ASP.net MVC 4 - Issues with pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, azure

I am completely new to Windows Azure and we don't have many people around the office that knows the technology, and those that do are out of the office and unreachable. so I turn to the community.

I have managed to:

- Export my SQL Database to Azure standards and import it in for both sites currently using it.
- Publish my sites to azure.

The issue is when I try and view any of the pages that require database information. That is, lets assume I try and view the locations page of my app at `somesite.azure.com/locations` this is suppose to pull in all my locatons instead I get: `sorry error occurred while processing your request` So I thought, this is a common database issue.

I was wrong - I think (you be the judge of that).

I made a second site that shares the database of the first site, this second site has a login, which goes to the database and checks your user name and password, well upon loggin in I get the same error, but it logs me in cause I redirect, but no data is displayed due to the error.

- Is there a way to log the error? because the logging I have used only saved the error pages, like 500, 404, 503 and so on. but these error pages don't tell me much of any thing.
- If it is a database issue, how can I get the specific error? When working in ASP and you throw and error the screen explodes into yellow anger. now I don't exactly want that, but I do want a stack trace.

This sounds like a database issue, but it might not be. Any ideas on how to trouble shoot. I don't find azures UI to be very friendly and the docs for this kind of thing are confusing.

The reason I don't think it is a database issue is because I let the publishing from VS 2010 to Azure create its own connection stirngs in the web.config file. but the fact that I cant display any data from the database points to that being the issue.

Comment: Did you replace the password in your Azure generated connection string? I had a similar problem and it was caused by not removing the {curly braces} around my password. It was a head desk moment...

Comment: there is no {} around the password, how ever there are three connection strings, when I published - I was able to do context and the databae, I did both, with the same conectionstring and thus got three connection strings, two context and one "default connection". How ever the username is username@randomstring

Comment: Have you deployed your site using "Azure Web Sites" or as a "Web Role" in a "Cloud Service"?